# problem with VM started with virsh

Tags: intel

A VM is started by using virsh but what I can see from the logs that there is a problem with huge pages.

```
tail /var/log/messages
Apr 19 17:33:12 selilsx1819 ovs-vswitchd[2435]: EAL: rte_mem_virt2phy(): read 0 bytes from /proc/self/pagemap but expected 8:
Apr 19 17:33:12 selilsx1819 ovs-vswitchd[2435]: EAL: rte_mem_virt2phy(): read 0 bytes from /proc/self/pagemap but expected 8:
Apr 19 17:33:12 selilsx1819 ovs-vswitchd[2435]: EAL: rte_mem_virt2phy(): read 0 bytes from /proc/self/pagemap but expected 8:
```

Any ideas ?

br Michael Granath

Comment: Please tell us the Ubuntu version. It has been years since the `/var/log/messages` file has been used.

Comment: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial